# Trying to embed PHP within PUGs property values

Tags: php, pug, pugjs

What I am trying to do (using gulp-pug, that uses pugjs):

```
<?='test!'?>
input(type='hidden', name="!{'<?=CMS::cmsQueryParam?>'}", value='loginForm')
```

and what ever I could find on the pug interpolation page, but it always gives me something like this:

```
test!
<input type="hidden" name="!{'&lt;?=CMS::cmsQueryParam?&gt;'}" value="loginForm">
```

Same happens here:

```
input(type='text', name='user', placeholder='Username', autofocus='', value="<?=$_REQUEST['user']?>")
```

.. the  will be converted to html entities. I have no clue how to prevent this.

Any ideas? Know of any posts, this could be a duplicate from?

Comment: Try `name="!{CMS::cmsQueryParam}"`

Comment: That will not help - as this is NOT PHP anymore. It has to be with <?= ... ?> to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffered code can be unescaped by starting with `!=`. *e.g.*

```
!= "<?='test!'?>"
```

Values for tag/mixin arguments can be unescaped by assigning with `!=` instead of `=`. *e.g.*

```
input(type='hidden', name!="<?=CMS::cmsQueryParam?>", value='loginForm')

input(type='text', name='user', placeholder='Username', autofocus='', value!="<?=$_REQUEST['user']?>")
```